# how to validate comma separate attribute value of XML using XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation

I want to validate this XML elements & attributes with XSD. For **export_format** attribute, I have comma separated value. How can I split the value in XSD and validate.

```
<REPORT name="Suppliers - All KPIs" report_design="/Phase2/Suppliers - All KPIs.RPTDESIGN" export_format="XLSX,PDF,CSV" show_filter="Y">
        <PREVILEGES condition="OR">
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_line_fill_rate_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_order_fill_rate_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_value_fill_rate_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_unit_fill_rate_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_delivery_punctuality_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_asn_timeliness_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_order_acceptance_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
                <PREVILEGE privilege_type="SP" privilege_name= "activeorders_invoice_accuracy_viewer"></PREVILEGE>
        </PREVILEGES>
    </REPORT>
```

Below is my code to validate. But, its only validating value with space.

[image]

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: There are tools which are creating automatically xsd files

Comment: @mybirthname I want to validate it in my java code while Unmarshalling the XML content to Java Object. how will I achieve this ?

Comment: Don't use comma-separation if you want help from XSD.  Use space-separation or use separate elements.

Comment: Please edit your question and replace your images with the actual XML text and code text, indented by four spaces so they appear as formatted blocks.  Images are hard to read, scale poorly, cannot be searched, cannot be copied for testing, and are of little to no use for sight impaired users.

Comment: you might be able to get somewhere with regexes (XSD pattern facet), but that would probably end up being unreliable, so the best way to proceed is as suggested by @kjhughes: use space-separation and then things will work.